# Python/Pandas: Filling new column after join

Tags: python, pandas

I have a single data frame containing a lot of information, the columns I am interested in have the following format after doing a left join in Pandas:

```
Company   Product   Brand   Model   Bonus   Bonus+   Price

 A         X        Sony     xxx     False   False    100
 A         X        Sony     xxx     True    False    110
 A         X        Sony     xxx     True    True     115
 A         X        Samsung  sth     False   False    95
 ...       ...      ...      ...     ...     ...      ...
```

I did a join on the company, product brand, and model to get an ordered data frame, now what I need is based on the above data frame, I have to calculate the difference in price between no bonus, bonus, and bonus plus in new 2 new columns (bonus difference from none, and bonus plus from bonus).

My current code is:

```
 merged = df.merge(df, on=["Company","Product","Make","Series"], how='left')
```

I had a previous code where I did a loop for each unique company and their product, brand, and model to create small data frames containing the very narrowed down info and then input the calculation. But it takes too long and it is not optimized.

My question is, how can I add the price difference between no bonus and bonus, and bonus and bonus plus for a set of company, product, brand, and model? Outcome should look like this:

```
 Company   Product   Brand   Model   Bonus   Bonus+   Price   BonusPrice 

 A         X        Sony     xxx     False   False    100     -
 A         X        Sony     xxx     True    False    110     10
 A         X        Sony     xxx     True    True     115     -
 A         X        Samsung  sth     False   False    95
 ...       ...      ...      ...     ...     ...      ...

Bonus+Price
-
-
5
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, please provide more details, precise description of where you're stuck, and fully reproducible examples

Comment: @mozway eddited it, hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will define a new column to give a `'price_type'` to each price

```
df['price_type'] = df['Bonus+'].map({True: 'Bonus+'}).fillna(df['Bonus'].map({True: 'Bonus', False: 'NoBonus'}))
```

that we can use to rebuild the dataframe with having the three prices for each model

```
step1 = df.set_index(['Company', 'Product', 'Brand', 'Model', 'price_type'])['Price'].unstack()
```

Then we calculate the differences

```
step1['Diff_Bonus_NoBonus'] = step1['Bonus'] - step1['NoBonus']
step1['Diff_Bonus+_Bonus'] = step1['Bonus+'] - step1['Bonus']
```

and reformat the dataframe

```
step2 = step1[['Diff_Bonus_NoBonus', 'Diff_Bonus+_Bonus']].reset_index().rename_axis('', axis=1)
```

Outcome:

```
Company Product Brand   Model   Diff_Bonus_NoBonus  Diff_Bonus+_Bonus
0   A   X   Samsung sth NaN NaN
1   A   X   Sony    xxx 10.0    5.0
```

Note that it's not exactly the way you asked for in the question, but this outcome looks pretty good to me. Is this good?

Comment: Thanks, Had to clean my data a bit due to duplicated rows but works nicely